# Plot two columns of data for each type (factor?) in R

Tags: r

I have searched the forum but can't quite figure out how to plot these data. I have a df called combined_numbers

```
ReactionType    Number of IDs   version
phosphorylates  1024            55
phosphorylates  951             56
cleaves         923             55
cleaves         904             56
transfers       685             55
transfers       652             56
hydrolyses      395             55
hydrolyses      360             56
transports      388             55
transports      385             56
```

I want create a barplot of each ReactionType with its "number of IDs" but side by side for each version. So the value of cleaves is side by side for version 55 and 56 etc.

I've tried the following and although it plots the values side by side, it duplicates the x axis so I get each ReactionType twice.

```
combined_plot <- barplot(combined_numbers$`Number of IDs`, names.arg=combined_numbers$ReactionType, 
               beside=TRUE, ylab="number of reaction types", 
               las=2, xlab="", las=2, ylim=c(0,1.2*max(combined_numbers$`Number of IDs`)),
               col=c("Blue", "Orange"), space = 0.3))
```

Like I said, works to a certain extent but not quite right. 
If there's a solution in ggplot, I'd like to see it 'cos I just can't get it to work with my data.

As always, your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Certainly a duplicate -- try searching for plotting factors, position dodge, etc... but this should do the trick. `library(ggplot2);

ggplot(df, aes(x = ReactionType, y = Number.of.IDs, fill = factor(version))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")` -- also [see this reference](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/) and observe the examples that utilize: `position = position_dodge()`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, again, the solution comes close but it doesn't correctly plot the y axis IDs (the bars are all the same height across the plot). Also, the x axis is still duplicating the types

Comment: I think I have it. When I used this ggplot(combined_numbers, aes(x = rt2, y = combined_numbers[,2], fill = version)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")